# JIRA 5 - Can't change issue type from "Bug" using IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, jira

Recently upgraded JIRA from 4 to 5. When using IE 8 to create a new issue we can't save the issue as anything other than the type "Bug". Works fine in Google Chrome or Firefox.

To reproduce in IE 8:

1. Click "Create Issue".
2. Change issue type from Bug to Enhancement.
3. Click in Summary text box.

--> Issue type changes back to bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this problem, too.  Assume you are running/accessing this on your intranet.

Under Tools-->Compatibility View-->Settings, uncheck "Display Intranet Site in Compatibility View" option.

Good luck!